# Kibana ssl configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-opendistro

I installed elasticsearch and kibana using this guide:

https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/install/

I created SSL for domain and using it in `kibana.yml` config.

```
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/key.pem
server.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/cert.pem
```

But, when I restart the service I am getting below error.

> sudo service kibana status
>   ● kibana.service - Kibana
>      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Tue 2019-05-14 19:39:21 UTC; 833ms ago
>     Process: 50944 ExecStart=/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>    Main PID: 50944 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> May 14 19:39:21 mts-elk systemd[1]: kibana.service: Unit entered failed state.
>
> May 14 19:39:21 mts-elk systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   May 14 19:39:21 mts-elk systemd[1]: kibana.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
>
> May 14 19:39:21 mts-elk systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
>
> May 14 19:39:21 mts-elk systemd[1]: kibana.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
>
> May 14 19:39:21 mts-elk systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana.
>
> May 14 19:39:21 mts-elk systemd[1]: kibana.service: Unit entered failed state.
>
> May 14 19:39:21 mts-elk systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.

I don't know where to look for kibana logs other than this.

Comment: how certain are you that those where you installed the certs?

Comment: I found the cause of it. It was a file permission issue.